# A doubt regarding symmetrical matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose I am given a relation for 3x3 matrix $$AA^{T}=A^{T}A$$ and $$B=A^{-1}A^{T}$$ 
So what will be $B.B^{T}$ ?
From first relation I concluded $A$ should be a symmetrical matrix and therefore $$B=A^{-1}A^{T}= A^{-1}A=I $$ therefore $B.B^{T}=I.I =I$
($I$ is identity matrix)
Is my logic correct ?

Comment: Matrices with the property $AA^T = A^TA$ are called normal. Not all normal matrices are symmetric, e.g. $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: So what would be correct way to do this problem?

Comment: @Three.OneFour : OK if Matrix is real, which I guess may be implied in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B.B^{T}=A^{-1}A^{T}.A{(A^{-1})}^{T}=A^{-1}AA^{T}(A^{T})^{-1}=I$

Comment: Simple and accurate , thanks